# DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName : only X first elements

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following code :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

if ($doc->loadHtml(curl_exec($ch)))
    $anchors = $doc->getElementById('comments')->getElementsByTagName('a');
?>
```

which searches through a distant page all the links (< a > tag) in the comments div.

I would like for this function to return only the 50 first < a > tags, without parsing through the whole div.
Is that possible ?
And if yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you are using DOMDocument, the whole div has been already parsed through. Even the whole document. ... http://php.net/LimitIterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XPath expression:

```
$elements = 50;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query(
    sprintf('//div[@id="comments"]/a[position() <= %d]', $elements)
);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/146554)

Comment: How would that work ? There's only one div with the ID "comments", which can contain over 10000 links.

EDIT : Answered before you edited with the XPath bit. I'll try that.

Comment: I would suggest first you check the item length of the `<a>` tags, if it is over 50, then do the looping upto that, else cut off to its length.

Comment: @roberto06 you can ofcourse also use the 'counter-solution', but then foreach over the `getElementsByTagName('a')` response.

Comment: @AmalMurali
It's (kind of) working.
I now face other problems : 
1. The container is not always a < div >, it can also be a <ul> or an < ol >, among others. I need to check the contanier with the id "comments", regardess of its tag name.
2. The links seldom are directly in the container, there's often another subdiv or a < p > or else. How can I retrieve the 50 first links in the container, regardless of their depth ?

Comment: @roberto06: Then change your expression to `'//*[@id="comments"]/a[position() <= %d]'`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks, that solved the container issue. However, I still have a problem while trying to retrieve links regardless of their depth.
See here : [Demo](https://eval.in/146644)

Comment: @roberto06: That is very different from your actual problem. Please post it as a new question.

Comment: Can't upvote, I don't have the required reputation. Such a shame, you've been very helpful. Anyway, I managed to solve this last issue, looks like I just needed to add parenthesis to `'//*[@id="comments"]//a'`, and it works like a charm, see here : [Demo](https://eval.in/146663)